# Visual Basic - How to creating functions for objects created at runtime

Tags: function, visual-studio-2012, procedure

I'm a bit of a newbie to Visual Basic 2013 Express.  In design-time I created a custom class "BoardGameGrid" and in it is an array of PictureBoxes (8x8) like BoardGameGrid.GridImage(X,Y).

During runtime I populate the array with values (IE: an Othello game board in my case), and I can manually (in code) place the appropriate game pieces onto the game board.

But now I am struggling to create the event handlers for things like DragEnter and DragDrop.  Any tips or suggestions?

This is how I would think it may work (of course it doesn't), but it may help get the idea across of what I'm trying to do and why it is not working for me.

```
BoardGameGrid.GridImage(0,0) = My.Resources.BluePiece
BoardGameGrid.GridImage(0,1) = My.Resources.AvailableSpot
```

So now that grid (0,1) is "available" I want the player to be drag their game piece (from pictureBox) INTO that spot and "take" that spot.  --stumpted--

AND

Because my grid is 8x8, can I programmatically do this?  or do I *need* to manually type out 64 Private Subs for DragEnter, and 64 more Private Subs for DragDrop event?

```
Private Sub BoardGameGrid.GridImage(0,1)_DragEnter(....)
   ....
End Sub
```

I know if I manually create each pictureBox at design time I can do everything that I want with the 128 event handler functions.  I guess I'm just being lazy and want to code smrt-er.

Any tips is appreciated

-Drew

Comment: Sure, you can loop thru the array and use **AddHandler** to wire up  all the PictureBoxes to the same DragEnter/DragDrop handlers.  The "sender" parameter in those events will tell you which PB was the source of the event.

Comment: Ah ha!  Thanks Idle, that looks like what I was trying to find.  Thanks for the tip